# How to install docker using powershell

Tags: docker, powershell

Need to install docker using powershell.
I have tried with the command

`Start-Process -Wait -FilePath C:\awsUsers\DockerDesktopInstaller.exe -Argument "/silent" -PassThru`

But getting error =>

```
 unknown command /silent
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
     31       3     1464       1888       0.08   9716   2 DockerDesktopInstaller
```

How to install docker using pershell script

Answer (score 0):

one of the quick way is to install with msi

```
$DockerInstaller = Join-Path $Env:Temp InstallDocker.msi

Invoke-WebRequest https://download.docker.com/win/stable/InstallDocker.msi -OutFile $DockerInstaller

## Now install it 
msiexec -i $DockerInstaller -quiet
```

**All these commands should run from an elevated host.**

Comment: hai @Turbot, Getting error when executing above script. error => DockerInstaller : The term 'DockerInstaller' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: correct the variable `$DockerInstaller`, i assume you have simple power shell knowledge and can interpret with above

Comment: yes. iam new in powershell. i didn't get the variable correction. what correction in $DockerInstaller? did you mean  $Env:Temp? can you re-write the above script?

Comment: is done, you can run this with your machine to see if works. the $DockerInstaller is variable to hold the downloaded msi to your temp folder, which should be good now.

Comment: I have temp folder in c drive. and run the above script & getting error. Invoke-WebRequest : 404 Not Found
Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: win/stable/InstallDocker.msi
RequestId: 9EE44A6C5KJPJ5QS
HostId: AfITTyxc8Ykw/Zm6uRxkFlPuVNKSk0W3WLa9ZVGhVusZpixleETtTln7nmwz83T0fOx4ubSdc4E=
An Error Occurred While Attempting to Retrieve a Custom Error Document
Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: error.html

Comment: change the Invoke-WebRequest path to 
`https://download.docker.com/win/beta/InstallDocker.msi`.

Comment: download works perfectly. but it is not installed. installation command not worked

Comment: What have you tried to identify the error instead posting here ? remember this need to run from an elevated host, and stackover is to proving hints not get your complete things works :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66633533/how-to-download-install-windows-docker-desktop-using-powershell => i have re-posted with the link

Comment: Can you check with the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66633533/how-to-download-install-windows-docker-desktop-using-powershell